# What is the difference between the following kernel Makefile terms: vmLinux, vmlinuz, vmlinux.bin, zimage & bzimage?

Tags: linux, kernel, file-format

While browsing through the Kernel Makefiles, I found these terms. So I would like to know what is the difference between `vmlinux`, `vmlinuz`, `vmlinux.bin`, `zimage` & `bzimage`?

Comment: outsize of I think zimage is gz compression and bzimage is bz compression... jut naming, afaik none of it means a damn thing. but I could be wrong.

Comment: There is also `vmlinuz.efi` used on Ubuntu 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330541/what-is-vmlinuz-efi

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**vmlinux**

This is the Linux kernel in an statically linked executable file format. Generally, you don't have to worry about this file, it's just a intermediate step in the boot procedure.

The raw vmlinux file may be useful for debugging purposes.

**vmlinux.bin**

The same as vmlinux, but in a bootable raw binary file format. All symbols and relocation information is discarded. Generated from `vmlinux` by `objcopy -O binary vmlinux vmlinux.bin`.

**vmlinuz**

The vmlinux file usually gets compressed with `zlib`. Since 2.6.30 `LZMA` and `bzip2` are also available. By adding further boot and decompression capabilities to vmlinuz, the image can be used to boot a system with the vmlinux kernel.  The compression of vmlinux can occur with zImage or bzImage.

The function `decompress_kernel()` handles the decompression of vmlinuz at bootup, a message indicates this:

```
Decompressing Linux... done
Booting the kernel.
```

**zImage** (`make zImage`)

This is the old format for small kernels (compressed, below 512KB). At boot, this image gets loaded low in memory (the first 640KB of the RAM).

**bzImage** (`make bzImage`)

The big zImage (this has nothing to do with `bzip2`), was created while the kernel grew and handles bigger images (compressed, over 512KB). The image gets loaded high in memory (above 1MB RAM).  As today's kernels are way over 512KB, this is usually the preferred way.

---

An inspection on Ubuntu 10.10 shows:

```
ls -lh /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.1M 2010-11-24 12:21 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-generic

file /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)
/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-23-generic: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 2.6.35-23-generic (buildd@rosea, RO-rootFS, root_dev 0x6801, swap_dev 0x4, Normal VGA
```

Comment: Where is this __decompress_kernel()__ function implementation located?

Comment: It is located at `/arch/$ARCH/boot/compressed/misc.c`, see here: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.c#L322

Answer (score 22):

**Do a verbose kernel build and search for the files**

This approach can give some insight, will never get out of date, and will help you to easily find which part of the build system is doing what.

Once you have a build configuration that generates one of the files, build with:

```
make V=1 |& tee f.log
```

Modify a comment on some C file to force a re-link (e.g. `init/main.c` is a good one) if you have already built previously.

Now, inspect `f.log` and search for the images of interest.

For example, on v4.19 we will conclude that:

```
init/main.c
|
| gcc -c
|
v
init/.tmp_main.o
|
| CONFIG_MODVERSIONS stuff
|
v
init/main.o
|
| ar T (thin archive)
|
v
init/built-in.a
|
| ar T (thin archive)
|
v
built-in.a
|
| ld
|
v
vmlinux (regular ELF file)
|
| objcopy
|
v
arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin
|
| GZIP
|
v
```

```
arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.gz
|
| .incbin
|
v
arch/x86/boot/compressed/piggy.S
|
| gcc -c
|
v
arch/x86/boot/compressed/piggy.o
|
| ld
|
v
arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux (regular ELF file with gzipped code)
|
| objcopy
|
v
arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin
|
| arch/x86/boot/tools/build.c
|
v
arch/x86/boot/bzImage
```

Thin archives are mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157629/linking-static-libraries-to-other-static-libraries/27676016#27676016 They are archives that just point other archives / objects instead of copying them.

The kernel moved from incremental linking to thin archives in v4.9 as described at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391965/what-is-partial-linking-in-gnu-linker/53959624#53959624

**Full log interpretation**

When we start reading the verbose build logs from the back up, first we see:

```
ln -fsn ../../x86/boot/bzImage ./arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage
```

so those two are just symlinked.

Then we search a bit further for `x86/boot/bzImage` and find:

```
arch/x86/boot/tools/build \
arch/x86/boot/setup.bin \
arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin \
arch/x86/boot/zoffset.h \
arch/x86/boot/bzImage
```

`arch/x86/boot/tools/build` is an executable, so we run it, see the help message:

```
Usage: build setup system zoffset.h image
```

and grep to find the source:

```
arch/x86/boot/tools/build.c
```

So this tool must be generating `arch/x86/boot/bzImage` from `arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin` and other files TODO what is the point of `build` exactly?

If we follow `arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin` we see that it is just an `objcopy` from `arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux`:

```
objcopy \
-O binary \
-R .note \
-R .comment \
-S arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux \
arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin
```

and `arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux` is just a regular ELF file:

```
ld \
-m elf_x86_64 \
-z noreloc-overflow \
-pie \
--no-dynamic-linker \
-T arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/head_64.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/misc.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/string.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/cmdline.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/error.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/piggy.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/cpuflags.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/early_serial_console.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/kaslr.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/kaslr_64.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/mem_encrypt.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/pgtable_64.o \
-o arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux
```

`ls -hlSr` says that `piggy.o` is by far the largest file, so we search for it, and it must come from:

```
gcc \
-Wp,-MD,arch/x86/boot/compressed/.piggy.o.d \
-nostdinc \
-Ilinux/arch/x86/include \
-I./arch/x86/include/generated \
-Ilinux/include \
-I./include \
-Ilinux/arch/x86/include/uapi \
-I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi \
-Ilinux/include/uapi \
-I./include/generated/uapi \
-include linux/include/linux/kconfig.h \
-D__KERNEL__ \
-m64 \
-O2 \
-fno-strict-aliasing \
-fPIE \
-DDISABLE_BRANCH_PROFILING \
-mcmodel=small \
-mno-mmx \
-mno-sse \
-ffreestanding \
-fno-stack-protector \
-Wno-pointer-sign \
-D__ASSEMBLY__ \
-c \
-o arch/x86/boot/compressed/.tmp_piggy.o \
arch/x86/boot/compressed/piggy.S
```

`.tmp_` prefix explained below.

`arch/x86/boot/compressed/piggy.S` contains:

```
.incbin "arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.gz"
```

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc/36295692#36295692

`arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.gz` comes from:

```
cat arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.relocs | \
gzip -n -f -9 > arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin.gz
```

which comes from:

```
objcopy  -R .comment -S vmlinux arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux.bin
```

which comes from:

```
LD      vmlinux
```

which does:

```
ld \
-m elf_x86_64 \
-z max-page-size=0x200000 \
--emit-relocs \
--build-id \
-o vmlinux \
-T ./arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds \
--whole-archive \
built-in.a \
--no-whole-archive \
--start-group \
lib/lib.a \
arch/x86/lib/lib.a \
--end-group \
.tmp_kallsyms2.o
```

`vmlinux` is huge, but all shown objects are tiny according to `ls -l`, so I researched and learned about a new `ar` feature I didn't know about: thin archives.

At:

```
AR      built-in.a
```

the build does:

```
ar \
rcsTPD \
built-in.a \
arch/x86/kernel/head_64.o \
arch/x86/kernel/head64.o \
arch/x86/kernel/ebda.o \
arch/x86/kernel/platform-quirks.o \
init/built-in.a \
usr/built-in.a \
arch/x86/built-in.a \
kernel/built-in.a \
certs/built-in.a \
mm/built-in.a \
fs/built-in.a \
ipc/built-in.a \
security/built-in.a \
crypto/built-in.a \
block/built-in.a \
lib/built-in.a \
arch/x86/lib/built-in.a \
drivers/built-in.a \
sound/built-in.a \
firmware/built-in.a \
arch/x86/pci/built-in.a \
arch/x86/power/built-in.a \
arch/x86/video/built-in.a \
net/built-in.a \
virt/built-in.a
```

`T` specifies the thin archive.

We can then see that all sub archives are also thin, e.g., since I modified `init/main.c`, we have:

```
ar \
rcSTPD \
init/built-in.a \
init/main.o \
init/version.o \
init/do_mounts.o \
init/do_mounts_initrd.o \
init/initramfs.o \
init/calibrate.o \
init/init_task.o
```

which finally comes from the C file through a command like:

```
gcc \
-Wp,-MD,init/.main.o.d \
-c \
-o \
init/.tmp_main.o \
/work/linux-kernel-module-cheat/submodules/linux/init/main.c
```

I can't find the `init/.tmp_main.o` to `init/main.o` step on the logs which is a shame... with:

```
git grep '\.tmp_'
```

we see that likely comes from `scripts Makefile.build` and is linked to `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` which I had enabled:

```
ifndef CONFIG_MODVERSIONS
cmd_cc_o_c = $(CC) $(c_flags) -c -o $@ $<

else
# When module versioning is enabled the following steps are executed:
# o compile a .tmp_<file>.o from <file>.c
# o if .tmp_<file>.o doesn't contain a __ksymtab version, i.e. does
#   not export symbols, we just rename .tmp_<file>.o to <file>.o and
#   are done.
# o otherwise, we calculate symbol versions using the good old
#   genksyms on the preprocessed source and postprocess them in a way
#   that they are usable as a linker script
# o generate <file>.o from .tmp_<file>.o using the linker to
#   replace the unresolved symbols __crc_exported_symbol with
#   the actual value of the checksum generated by genksyms

cmd_cc_o_c = $(CC) $(c_flags) -c -o $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F) $<

cmd_modversions_c =                             \
    if $(OBJDUMP) -h $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F) | grep -q __ksymtab; then     \
        $(call cmd_gensymtypes_c,$(KBUILD_SYMTYPES),$(@:.o=.symtypes))  \
            > $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F:.o=.ver);                 \
                                        \
        $(LD) $(KBUILD_LDFLAGS) -r -o $@ $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F)       \
            -T $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F:.o=.ver);                \
        rm -f $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F) $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F:.o=.ver);        \
    else                                    \
        mv -f $(@D)/.tmp_$(@F) $@;                  \
    fi;
endif
```

Analysis done with [this config](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/65d33ab11e721a48fb11435896fbab1e12ea75ab#kernel-configs-about) which contains `CONFIG_KERNEL_GZIP=y`.

**aarch64 `arch/arm64/boot/Image`**

Just an uncompressed `objcopy` from `vmlinux`:

```
objcopy  -O binary -R .note -R .note.gnu.build-id -R .comment -S vmlinux arch/arm64/boot/Image
```

`vmlinux` is obtained in basically the exact same way as for x86 though the thin archives.

**`arch/arm/boot/zImage`**

Very similar to X86 with a zipped `vmlinux`, but no magic `build.c` step. Call chain summary:

```
objcopy -O binary -R .comment -S  arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux arch/arm/boot/zImage

ld \
-EL \
--defsym _kernel_bss_size=469592 \
-p \
--no-undefined \
-X \
-T arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/misc.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/decompress.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/string.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/hyp-stub.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/lib1funcs.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/ashldi3.o \
arch/arm/boot/compressed/bswapsdi2.o \
-o arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux

gcc \
-c \
-o arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.o \
linux/arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy.S

.incbin "arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy_data"

cat arch/arm/boot/compressed/../Image | gzip -n -f -9 > arch/arm/boot/compressed/piggy_data

objcopy -O binary -R .comment -S  vmlinux arch/arm/boot/Image
```

**QEMU v4.0.0 can boot from bzImage but not vmlinux**

This is another important practical difference: https://superuser.com/questions/1451568/booting-an-uncompressed-kernel-in-qemu

Answer (score 3):

I don't usually use Wikipedia to understand things like this but it's surprisingly useful for [vmlinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux).

> As the Linux kernel matured, the size of the kernels generated by users grew beyond the limits imposed by some architectures, where the space available to store the compressed kernel code is limited. The bzImage (big zImage) format was developed to overcome this limitation by splitting the kernel over non-contiguous memory regions.

> The bzImage was compressed using gzip until Linux 2.6.30
>
> The bzImage file is in a specific format. It contains concatenated bootsect.o + setup.o + misc.o + piggy.o. piggy.o contains the gzipped vmlinux file in its data section.

[image]

I know I've only partially answered the question - I'm still trying to understand it myself.

Answer (score 1):

**vmlinux**:

A non-compressed and non-bootable Linux kernel file format, just an intermediate step to producing `vmlinuz`.

**vmlinuz**:
A compressed and bootable Linux kernel file. It is actually `zImage` or `bzImage` file.

**zImage**:
For old kernels, just fit `640k` ram size.

**bzImage**:
`Big zImage`, no `640k` ram size limit, can much larger.

Please refer this document: [vmlinuz Definition](http://www.linfo.org/vmlinuz.html).

Answer (score 1):

*bzImage* is the target used for x86 architectures working with PC BIOS. In contrast, *zImage* is an architecture-specific target most commonly used for embedded devices and works well with their bootloaders.