# Is vmlinuz and bzImage really the same?

Tags: boot, u-boot

I just stumbled upon [this page](http://www.linfo.org/vmlinuz.html), which says that bzImage and vmlinuz are identical.

> bzImage is then copied using the cp (i.e., copy) command to the /boot directory and simultaneously renamed vmlinuz with a command such as
>
> ```
> cp /usr/src/linux/arch/i386/linux/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz
> ```

This is worrying me, as up to now my understanding was as follows:

- **`vmlinux`**: Plain linux ELF file just the way it was created by the
  linker, including symbols and everything.
- **`vmlinuz`**: gzipped `vmlinux` file which got stripped of all its symbols
- **`zImage`**: bootsect.o + setup.o + misc.o + piggy.o (piggy.o contains the piggy-backed `vmlinuz`). `zImage` is bootable because it can decompress and run the kernel it contains.
- **`bzImage`**: same as `zImage` except that it is built slightly differently which enables it to carry bigger kernels.

Can you tell me who is correct?

I am aware of [this Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5602/103271), but it doesn't answer my question explicitely.  Implicitely, however, I feel that it is backing my understanding.

---

### Bonus question

Which of the files above does `uImage` contain?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-kernel-makefile-terms-vmlinux-vml

Answer (score 14, accepted):

“vmlinuz” as a **format** name does mean “gzipped vmlinux file which got stripped of all its symbols”. However, as a **file** name, `vmlinuz` is often used for any kernel image which is in a compressed format that a bootloader supports, such as the zimage format or the bzimage format. The name `vmlinuz` is popular on x86 distributions, regardless of the actual format of the file (usually bzimage). The name `uImage` generally indicates yet another format, used by the [U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) bootloader which is popular on embedded systems; a `uImage` file contains a U-Boot-specific header followed by a kernel image which can be in several formats (see [sawdust's answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322304/image-vs-zimage-vs-uimage/22338835#22338835) for more information).