# vmlinuz <-> uImage

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, compiling

I would like to ask if I can make a regular kernel build with cross compiler (make uImage), and then move it into ubuntu machine (replacing vmlinuz in some way).

This is can save me a lot of time, becuase building for ubuntu with fakeroot, and .bld , takes a lot of time (in my computer almost 2 hours).

I understood that it is possible, but found no documentation on this issue.

Regards,
Ran

Comment: The uImage file contains header info for u-boot. Are you using u-boot as your boot loader? What about 'make zImage'?

Comment: Look at question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-kernel-makefile-terms-vmlinux-vml?rq=1